# Beginner in Python - Filter list of strings based on condition

Tags: python, list

I'm new with Python, and I'm trying to filter a list of DNA sequences (strings) based on a condition.

Given my random list of DNA sequences, I want to keep in the list only the sequences in which A=T and C=G.

This is what I did so far, but I obtain the position of the string and not the string. I wonder how could I obtain a string in my output. Any advice would be great, thank you!

This is what I tried to do so far:

```
import numpy as np 
BASES = ('A','C','T','G')
P = (0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3)

def random_dna_sequence(length): 
    return ''.join(np.random.choice(BASES, p=P) for _ in range(length)) 

dna = [random_dna_sequence(20) for _ in range(300)] #dna1=300 sequences of 20 characters each
print(dna)
```

Then, I tried to obtain the list of sequences that only accomplish this condition:

```
# Obtain a list dna_2 with DNA sequences that accomplish this condition only
dna_2 = [i for i in range(len(dna)) if (dna[i].count('A'))== (dna[i].count('T')) and (dna[i].count('C'))== (dna[i].count('G'))]
print(dna_2)
```

My output is returning the position of the sequences that accomplish this condition, but not the sequence itself (the sequence):

```
[29, 41, 66, 85, 88, 117, 142, 174, 201, 226, 231, 246, 250, 279, 294, 299, 306, 338, 370, 372, 381, 404, 420, 486, 519, 579]
```

And my desire output should be:

```
['AACTGACTTG', ...]
```

Thank you all!

Comment: In the second list comprehension you need dna[i] for i in ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dna_2 = [i for i in range(len(dna)) if (dna[i].count('A'))== (dna[i].count('T')) and (dna[i].count('C'))== (dna[i].count('G'))]
```

`i` here refers to the index (which you probably know but mistyped since you *are* using `dna[i]` when calling `.count`).

You can change it to `dna_2 = [dna[i] for i ...]` or better yet, just iterate directly over the sequence strings instead of superficially using the indexes:

```
dna_2 = [sequence for sequence in dna if sequence.count('A') ... ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! I didn't realise that you gave me the solution as well :D Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

That should be

```
dna_2 = [dna[i] for i in range(len(dna)) if (dna[i].count('A'))== (dna[i].count('T')) and (dna[i].count('C'))== (dna[i].count('G'))]
```

instead.

Comment: Are you asking or answering?

Comment: Ok, answering ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is exactly was I was looking for. I wasn't using correctly the 'i' index in the formula. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

For a more elegant solution just iterate over the list rather than iterating over the index:

```
dna_2 = [this_dna for this_dna in dna if (this_dna.count('A'))== (this_dna.count('T')) and (this_dna .count('C'))== (this_dna.count('G'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

### filter() function -> performance gain

You can just use the filter function with a lambda expression. The filter function algorithm is optimized under the hood.

You should learn the lambda syntax though. Lambdas are just inline functions.

Here is the syntax for your problem:

```py
random_dna_sequencies = [random_dna_sequence(20) for _ in range(300)]

filtered_dna_sequencies_iterator = filter(lambda dna_sequency:
                                          dna_sequency.count('A') == dna_sequency.count('T') and
                                          dna_sequency.count('C') == dna_sequency.count('G'),
                                          random_dna_sequencies)

filtered_dna_sequencies_list = list(filtered_dna_sequencies_iterator)
print(filtered_dna_sequencies_list)
```

Let me explain:

1. the `filter()` function receives two parameters:

   1. The second parameter is the iterator/list you want to filter.
   2. The first parameter is a lambda expression. Each element from the list `random_dna_sequencies` (which means each dna sequency) is passed to the lambda function as argument, named as `dna_sequency`. The pameter is tested in the condition `dna_sequency.count('A') == dna_sequency.count('T') and dna_sequency.count('C') == dna_sequency.count('G')`. Only the ones who satisfy the condition are returned to the variable `filtered_dna_sequencies_iterator`.
2. the `filter()` function returns an iterator, not a list. If you want the object only to place it in a `for` loop, use the iterator. If you want to store the object on lists, you use the cast `filtered_dna_sequencies_list = list(filtered_dna_sequencies_iterator)`.